# How to place two Text with different fontSize in row with bottom places in the same line

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to set 2 different font-size and Opposite corner. Due to size differs they appear up and down in same row. I need to align their bottom in the same line.

```
<h4 className="vertical-timeline-element-subtitle"> 
  {event_tag} 
  <span className="creatorstyle"> 
    {"(" + created_by + ")"}
  </span>
  <span className='datestyle'>
    {format(new Date(created_at), 'LLLL do yyyy h:mm a')}
  </span>
</h4>
```

The above code shows something like this:

[image]

I am trying to make "Customer Called In (Gowri)     March 7th 2023 4:45 PM" in the same line.

Comment: When you say 'their bottom' - it so happens that nothing in the text you have shown has descenders, but if they had are you talking about the baseline being the same (as if they were written on the same line) or the very bottom of the characters being inline?

Answer (score 2):

use `flexbox` :

```
.vertical-timeline-element-subtitle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```